# Do I need live REST API credentials for PayPal?

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

After countless searches and googling I've been unable to figure out the simplest question.

Am I required to use the "Live" credentials instead of the "Test" credentials when making API calls to PayPal?

All I am trying to do is request the current PayPal balance and display it back to an internal PHP application but am unsure whether or not I need to be using live credentials.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Have you tried it? The simple solution seems to be trying it with your test creds and seeing if you get the expected response.... 2. It seems logical (to me at least) that if you are attempting to access live data you would need live credentials. I could be wrong though; this is just my first instinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use live accounts if you are testing. Login here https://developer.paypal.com you can then setup accounts to use in the sandbox by clicking on the applications tab and then sandbox accounts. You should setup two accounts - business and personal. Use the personal account to send payments to the business account.

You also need to set the correct endpoint (i.e. the url you will call). For sandbox this is something like https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

You also need to authenticate yourself with your apps credentials (different from paypal credentials) These can be found on your developer account profile. Once you have authenticated a request, you will then be sent an API token. This token must then be used in all subsequent requests.

Also not that paypal have just released a new [REST api](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/). Makes requesting much easier.

Start off here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Comment: I agree.  The new REST API makes things a lot easier.  What is somewhat annoying is the fact your oauth token expires in 8 hours so you manually have to track that on your solution's end.

Answer (score 1):

You can test with your sandbox account.
To test with the REST API's in the sandbox, you would want to use your facilitator account that is created for you in your developer account.
This should be the first email address listed under your test email accounts in your developer account.

You would then want to use your REST API Credentials for this account (including your client id and secret as well to generate an access token -- for more information on authentication using our REST API's, please see the [following section on our API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers).

Are  you sure however that you want to use the REST API's?
We're very happy with them, but you cannot retrieve your current balance with them at the moment. For that you would want to use our [GetBalance API call](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getbalance-api-operation-nvp).
You'll want to use live credentials for GetBalance against our live endpoint (https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp typically) if you want to retrieve the balance of a live account, and vice-versa for a sandbox account.

For example, a typical example to get the balance of an account would look as follows:

```
METHOD=GetBalance&USER=your_API_username&PWD=your_API_password&SIGNATURE=your_API_signature&VERSION=96.0
```

**GET** or **POST** this (it doesn't really matter which, with our non-REST API's) to https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp or https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/ for live or sandbox respectively, and it will return the current balance of the account to you.

See also our [guide to Sandbox transactions](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox).